# How to enable video playing on a second monitor using Intel graphics?

Tags: 10.10, video, intel-graphics, mplayer

On Windows overlay-rendered video playback was working correct on all the monitors. On Linux I not only have to place my external monitor below (instead of right to) my laptop's panel to enable its full resolution , but video player displays blue square instead of the video picture if placed on the second display. Can I overcome it other way than by using software video rendering?

I use Intel 82852/855GM graphics and Ubuntu 10.10. I mainly use raw mplayer to play video.

**UPDATE**: I've noticed, that the problem only takes place when I use a big (1600x1200) monitor (placed under the laptop's panel, otherwise it's impossible to use that big resolution with Intel driver (or just my oldie Intel card)). When I use a 1024x768 external panel (placed to the right of the laptop's panel), overlay video rendering seems to work ok on both screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As updating video drivers does not help, I've found a workaround. It's to launch a player for the same file (I use raw mplayer) twice (and then close the first instance) - first playback window shows a blue square and a second shows a picture as it is meant to. Note that the problem only occurs on big monitors - if a second monitors is 1024x768 there is no problem, if a monitors is 1600x1200 the problem occurs even if it is the only monitors turned on.

Answer (score 3):

Install the xorg-edgers drivers: https://edge.launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers

I had problems with the default drivers in Ubuntu 10.10 on an 945GM Intel card when the total screen area was bigger than 2048x2048. I have installed the xorg-edgers drivers and it seems to be working fine now (albeit no 3D).

To try things without messing your setup, install Ubuntu on a USB stick, boot it, install the xorg-edgers drivers, reboot on the USB stick and see if things work better.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. This does not seem to help, but the PPA you've linked to is a good thing to know.